# React, Redux, Immutable - cannot access JSON key within mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, immutable.js

Hopefully a really simple one (react newbie here!) but I cannot seem to access a specific key within the state property returned from a react/redux/immutable reducer.

Consider the following where I wish to return the value of `state.api.authenticated`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log('DEBUG 1: ', JSON.stringify(state));
  console.log('DEBUG 2: ', JSON.stringify(state.api));
  console.log('DEBUG 3: ', JSON.stringify(state.api.authenticated));
  return {
    authenticated: state.api.authenticated
  };
}
```

This returns the following:

```
DEBUG 1:  {"modals":{},"routing":{"locationBeforeTransitions":null},"api":{"loading":false,"requests":{},"errors":{"last":null},"data":{"articles":[]},"authenticated":true},"articles":{"to_read_count":0},"form":{"signin":{"registeredFields".... (redacted for brevity)

DEBUG 2:  {"loading":false,"requests":{},"errors":{"last":null},"data":{"articles":[]},"authenticated":true}

DEBUG 3:  undefined
```

So clearly `state.api.authenticated` IS in the `state` object and yet I cannot access it!

Any advice much appreciated.

---

Edit 1: Reducer initial state definition:

```
const initialState = Map({
  loading: false,
  requests: OrderedMap({}),
  errors: Map({
    last: null
  }),
  data: Map({
    articles: List()
  }),
  authenticated: false
});
```

Reducer setting value:

```
case AUTH_USER:
      return state.set('authenticated', true);
```

Comment: Did you try logging `this.props.authenticated` in your component ?

Comment: try this `state.getIn(['api', 'authenticated'])`

Comment: Thanks @NicolaeMaties - is getIn not used for a map? FYI I just added the initialState. Authenticated should be a boolean.

Comment: this one `state.api.getIn(['authenticated']).toJS()` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: ok, thanks to the comments I found `state.api.get` worked:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    authenticated: state.api.get('authenticated')
  };
};
```